# Small example on getting Cairo graphics to work with MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, cairo

I have some legacy MFC apps, and I'd like to use the Cairo drawing engine to add some charts and graphs.

I'm searching for a small example of how to get that to work.  Basically, once I've created a PNG or GIF file, how do I get that show up in an MFC CView window?

My google-fu is not finding any good clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my demo samples,

```
// cairo_surface_t *surface;
// cairo_t *cr;

// surface = call_win32_surface_create_with_dib_T(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 240, 80);
// cr = call_create_T (surface);

// call_surface_write_to_png_T (surface, "hello.png");


HDC src = call_win32_surface_get_dc_T(surface); // <--------
BitBlt(dest, 0, 0, 240, 80, src, 0,0, SRCCOPY); // <--------
```

Assuming that you already have a surface you can use something like the above sample.
`dest` is the `HDC` handle to the window you want to render the cairo surface.

**Update:** [CView::OnDraw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6htdchf.aspx)

You should implement the OnDraw() method for your CView (inherited?) class.

You can use the pDC pointer to draw the cairo surface, ie:

```
pDC->BitBlt(0, 0, 240, 80, src, 0,0, SRCCOPY); // "HDC src" is mentioned above
```

Comment: Do you have a link to more samples?  I've done years and years of MFC programming, but only with the simple builtins (dialogs, menus, etc).  The last time I did charting, I used a library (ChartFX 98, if that tells you how long ago it was), and they handled all the drawing.

Comment: @Eric H., see my update. I don't have CView-specific samples. If you still need help on how to use a CView object or about Cairo API, I could find some samples, but not at the moment.